# Meaning of に in 本当に

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-に

In the sentence これは[本当]{ほんと}に[高]{たか}いです, meaning "*This is really expensive*", I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of に, which usually has some connotation of "to", "on", or "at".

This is a phrase presented in Memrise Japanese Level 3, and I'm trying to start understanding the grammatical sense of the phrases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adjectives can often be used 'adverbially' (though they are generally not analysed by Japanese grammarians as 副詞) by adding に rather than な or in this case の.

Comment: So in this case, if 本当 => *true*, then 本当に => *truly* or *really*?

Comment: @TimD Yes, basically.

Answer (score 5):

If you really wanted to force a preposition into an English translation of 本当に so that it made more sense, you could say the the に is equivalent to the 'In' in 'In reality'.

Comment: I thought of the exact same thing! Haha! By the way, welcome to Japanese Stack Exchange!  :)

Answer (score 2):

`に` means "to."

e.g.)
`あなたに` - To you

`本当に` - To the truth / I will hand this over the truth / truly